# Sharing a timestamp from thread to another

Tags: multithreading, time, rust, atomic

I have a worker thread that is running in a loop, occasionally doing work. I would like to have a manager thread that [keeps a watchful eye on whether the first thread has done any work recently](http://cdn.quotesgram.com/img/25/66/1934361440-Bill-Lumbergh-Gary-Cole-Office-Space.jpg).

I think the simplest way to do this is to have a variable containing a timestamp; when the worker thread does some work, it writes the current time to the variable, and when the manager thread wants to check on the worker, it reads the time from the variable and measures the difference from the current time.

Firstly, does this variable need to be atomic? My instinct is to use an atomic when communicating between threads, but in this case, there is no read-modify-write cycle, and only one thread is making the update. The time value should be small enough to fit into a single word, so perhaps there is no worry about word tearing either. Should it still be atomic to somehow encourage timely propagation between threads? If not, what is the right way to share the timestamp?

Secondly, what is a suitable type for representing the timestamp, and how do i get an instance of it? std::time::Instant seems like the obvious choice, but it's not Sync or Send, and i don't know how i'd have an atomic one. Is there a better choice?

Comment: If one thread is writing, it absolutely needs to be atomic or otherwise synchronised.  You also don't necessarily need a timestamp; a simple atomic flag could do if all you want to know is "has the thread done something since last time I checked?".

Answer (score 4):

What i've done so far is write my own AtomicInstant. The content of an Instant is platform-specific and well-hidden, but it can be converted into an offset from another Instant, in the form of Duration, which can in turn be converted into a nanosecond count. That, in turn, can be stuffed into a usize, which will work as long as the times you're measuring don't get too big with respect to your machine's word size (a day is about 2**46 nanoseconds; a 64-bit machine can measure about 350 years). That chain of transformations can all be reversed to read a value.

The code looks like this (edited slightly, so it's possible this is wrong):

```
struct AtomicInstant {
    base: Instant,
    offset: AtomicUsize,
}

impl AtomicInstant {
    fn new(base: Instant) -> AtomicInstant {
        AtomicInstant {
            base: base,
            offset: AtomicUsize::new(0),
        }
    }

    fn load(&self, order: Ordering) -> Instant {
        let offset_nanos = self.offset.load(order) as u64;
        let secs = offset_nanos / 1_000_000_000;
        let subsec_nanos = (offset_nanos % 1_000_000_000) as u32;
        let offset = Duration::new(secs, subsec_nanos);
        return self.base + offset;
    }

    fn store(&self, val: Instant, order: Ordering) {
        let offset = val - self.base;
        let offset_nanos = offset.as_secs() * 1_000_000_000 + offset.subsec_nanos() as u64;
        self.offset.store(offset_nanos as usize, order);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std::time::Instant` actually does implement `Send`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cc542e3dedbafe1b0150e2d110d0d65a&version=stable&backtrace=1). You don't see all the types that implement `Send` or `Sync` in the documentation; you only see negative implementations (e.g. `Rc`) and explicit implementations (e.g. `Arc`). `Send` and `Sync` use a language feature (that is still unstable as of Rust 1.15.1) that makes the compiler implement them for custom types if all their fields implement the trait (i.e. if all the fields are `Send`, the type is `Send`; likewise with `Sync`). The explicit implementations (which must be marked as `unsafe` because the traits are defined as `unsafe`) exist to override negative implementations (the root of which are the raw pointer types; the other negative implementations are completely superfluous but they're there for documentation purposes). Naturally, when a type has private fields, you can't tell just by looking at the documentation if that type implements `Send` and/or `Sync`. The best way to check is to just try to compile a bit of code that requires it.

Therefore, if you need a shared, mutable `Instant`, just use an `Arc<Mutex<Instant>>`!

Comment: That's a huge revelation about Sync and Send! It's a real shame they aren't included in the generated documentation too, but i can live with it, using your compiling trick.

Comment: I'd like to avoid a mutex if possible. The manager thread has a lot of time on its hands, but the worker thread is doing work where, potentially, every cycle counts, so i'd like the fastest possible way to share the data.